# Firebase+Chrome app(no extension)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to implement Firebase in a Chrome app ( packaged app before ). I trying include this in my manifest :

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cdn.firebase.com https://*.firebaseio.com; object-src 'self'",
```

but i found this issue : content security policy' is only allowed for extensions and legacy packaged apps, but this is a packaged app. exist other way to implement Firebase in chrome apps? Is possible?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A sandboxed iframe, probably.

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/okKgOaZlBBQ

Answer (score 1):

content_security_policy is applicable only for chrome extension not for packaged app.

Comment: Can't we go with Sandboxing?

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/sandbox